# Estimating Statistics of a Non-Parametric PDF

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn, statsmodels

Say I have a numpy vector with data and that I fit a non-parametric  distribution to it. For example, I went through [this really good guide](http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/01/kernel-density-estimation/) and comparison of methods for KDE estimation, and I chose to use `scikit-learn` with CV validation for bandwitch selection. Specifically:

```
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
grid = GridSearchCV(KernelDensity(),
                    {'bandwidth': np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, 30)},
                    cv=20) # 20-fold cross-validation
grid.fit(data[:, None])
print(grid.best_params_)

# Use the resulting fit to get a PDF on a given grid
kde    = grid.best_estimator_
x_grid = np.linspace(0, 100, 100)
pdf    = np.exp(kde.score_samples(x_grid[:, None]))
```

So far so good. My question now is, how can I measure **statistics** of this PDF? For example MAP, first-order, second-order moments, etc? I could of course code them up manually (they are relatively easy after all), but are there any builtins that help with this work?